# (JAVA) Initializing object - calling method in one line

Tags: java, variables, methods, null

```
public perform Ulti (Location origin, int number) { 

        Map i = new Map(origin, i.getDestination(), number);

}
```

The constructor of Map is (Location n, Location m, int k);

My question is, I don't know the destination, but there is a method within Map called getDestination(). I know the origin **fed into first parameter**, how can I use the method of the newly created object?

note: Map object cannot be null; //so i am unsure of what other placeholder might i use

Comment: This can't work because Map i isn't initialized. 
Anyway, if you have a method in i, to get the destination, why you need to pass the destination to i as parameter? You can't just call getDestination() inside the Map constructor like this.getDestination()?

Comment: So your `Map` is a concrete class?

Comment: (This can't work because `i` isn't in scope yet.. never mind it not being initialized; this results in an error like "*cannot find symbol* .. variable i".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable that holds destination so you have to set it first

for example :

```
map i = new map(); 
i.setDistination("----");
String distination = i.getDistination();
```

but in your example you can simply type a destination or get it from other object.

Comment: This won't work - map has 3 paramaters. (origin, destination, number).
I don't need to set the destination, the destination is predefined in Map class. I need to getDestination to be a parameter of the object.

Comment: if destination haven't been set , so what do you want to return !! 
 
an example : you can make a constructor that does not receive destination , to find destination and then get destination

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following thing inside your `Map` class -

```
class Map{

   Location origin;
   Location destination;
   int number;

   //create a no argument constructor so that your Map can 
   // be created without any constructor whenever required
   Map(){

   }

   //create a constructor with two argument
   Map(Location origin, int number){
      this.origin = origin;
      this.number = number;
   }  


  //getter and setter methods.

}
```

Now you can create `Map` instance/object like this -

```
Map i = new Map(origin, number);
Location m = // some code for generating Location as destination
i.setDestination(m);
```

Comment: Thanks , I didn't know you could create an empty constructor. Seems to be looking good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call and object's method without it being created. And if you could, it wouldn't make sense to pass a value that the object already has per se. What 'is' the destination? If you have other ways to access it just add an empty constructor to Map. 
Like this

```
public class Map{
     public Map(){

     }
     //Rest of code
}
```

And now you can create the object without the destination:
    Map i = new Map();
and then set the destination once you have it.